# Python and list compare

Tags: python, string, list, string-comparison

```py
list1 = ['bd 100bd has 15', 'bd 100abd has 0', 'bd 100bbd has 10', 'bd 100cbd has  0', 'bd 100dbd has 0']

list2 = ['100', '100a']

new_list = []
idx =0 

for item in list1:
    if any(x in line for x in list2):
        new_list.insert(list1)
        idx += 1

    
print(new_list)
```

I am trying to print a new list that will compare the two lists and if `list1` has the string from `list2` (i.e 100) it will print the string.

```py
new_list = ['bd 100bd has 15', 'bd 100abd has 0']
```

Comment: I am confused why your result does not include every observation from your initial list as each of the examples has the string 100 present?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []

for item_1 in list_1:
    for item_2 in list_2:
        if item_2 in item_1:
            if item_1 not in result:
                result.append(item_1)

print(len(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at if a string is **EQUAL** to a string from list1, this should work. If you are looking for if it contains it, then your solution should work.

```
for item in list1:
   if (item in list2 or item in list2):
       new_list.append(item)
       idx += 1
```

If you have more elements in list1, use a nested for loop and check for each individual element **in** list2